# Sphinx Style change

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I noticed at somepoint between versions ~3.5.4 and ~4.0.1 there was a change to style of autogenerated signatures in sphinx. To be precise, before it looked like:

[image]

and now it looks like:

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve the old style look in the newest version of sphinx?

Comment: This is dependent upon the theme you use. It looks like [sphinx_rtd_theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme) which recently released v1.0.0. See https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#adding-custom-css-or-javascript

Comment: https://foolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/models.html#foolbox.models.PyTorchModel looks just fine, where does this screenshot come from?